# Describe vector subspaces and FInd basis for sum of vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help with this problem: [image]

For part a), I thought to write $v_1,v_2,v_3$ in their vector form with respect to the standard basis. Then I will group them together into a matrix and row reduce the matrix to retrieve a set of linearly independent vectors. I do not know how to describe the subspaces with three independent conditions as the question asks.

For part b), I thought of doing the same as finding a basis in part a).

I do not know what to do in part c), I do not suppose the rank-nullity theorem helps too much, does it?

Comment: Your plan sounds good. Go ahaed.

Comment: Can you help me with describing the subspace?

Comment: Once you finish the process, you should get a basis of three elements for $W$. Using that, it is easy to get 3 conditions that describe or generate the subspace $W$.